# TypeORM run transaction on provider level?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have two tables `account` and `address`. `account` relies on `address` meaning in order to create an `account`, you must create an `address` first and get it's `address.id`.

I can't rely on my database in-case of either `address` creation fails or `account` creation fails.

Therefore I have to run a **transaction**.

If I run a transaction in my **provider** which is the class that injects all of the required services in order to do the operation that I need which is account creation, in my case it uses `addressService` and `accountService`, I have been told that this is an anti pattern to do because transactions and everything related to database must be ran in the `repository`.

But how? I have to run operation in two different repositories `addressRepository` and `accountRepository`.

What is the best practice to start and commit a transaction when you are using more than one repository on two different services?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create another **Service** (addressAcountService) and only work in this service the operations in which you use both entities, this would the safest approach I think.

On the services approach, I don't see any anti-pattern in adding a layer in the repository logic, as I can see separating repositories into services makes the system even more **scalable** and **maintainable** because you are preventing code duplication and you can even prevent access to different places in the project that you would not want them to modify the database without control, and it even prevents that in future if you want to change to a different **DBMS** or even the **ORM** you will only have to change the dependency and not the whole entity logic of the CRUD operations. An example, imagine that on the early development of your application you decided to hard **DELETE** all the rows in the database when the user wanted it to, as the system started growing you detected that the delete operations where not the most safe of the operations because you got a lot of cascaded deletions and in some cases it took ages to delete one row (I am exaggerating a little bit here) then you want to change it to a soft (**UPDATE** a flag) delete, if you are on the approach of using the repository for all the operations this would be a headache because you need to change every part of code in which you use the repository and its relations as it cascades and we are not talking about the **DELETE** operation only, you gotta take care of the **SELECTs** **UPDATEs** and even on the **INSERTs** in which you look for unique attributes. on the Service approach you change the logic in the operations you put available to the different controllers and that is it or even you can create another service and replace the dependency.